# Как посчитать количество в строк в списке?

Tags: python, строки, list

Подскажите, как посчитать количество строк в данном списке с помощью цикла?

```
mixture_list = [True, 1, -10, 'hello', False, 'string_1', 123, 2.5, [1, 2], 'another']
```

Comment: 1) Создать переменную для счетчика и инициализировать ее нулем; 2) Пройтись в цикле по всем значениям списка; 3) Поставить условие: является ли данное значение строкой; 4) При срабатываннии данного условия увеличить счетчик на единицу; 5) После прохождения цикла получить количество строк в списке из счетчика;

Comment: Вы собирались решать данную задачу на `python`?

Comment: `sum(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), mixture_list))`

Answer (score 3):

Считаем все элементы типа str в списке:

```
count = 0
mixture_list = [True, 1, -10, 'hello', False, 'string_1', 123, 2.5, [1, 2], 'another']
for element in mixture_list:
    if isinstance(element, str):
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Думаю, все предельно ясно. Вас может смутить лишь функция isinstance , - именно она и используется для проверки того, является ли element строкой(str)

Answer (score 0):

Загорелся я стилем генератора...

```py
count = len(None for element in mixture_list if isinstance(element, str))
```

Comment: Старайтесь давать чуть более развернутые ответы. Неподготовленные читатели и новички не смогут понять, что здесь происходит и ценность Вашего ответа для них очень сильно упадет.

Answer (score 0):

В функциональном стиле:

```py
count = list(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str), mixture_list)).count(True)
```

Comment: в предлрженных правках, пожалуйста, старайтесь не изменять смысл, сообщения автора и ни в коем случае не менять ничего в коде, кроме форматирования. Если пользователь говорит, что он вызвал метод `X`, а Вам кажется, что он вызвал метод `Y` не спешите заменять в сообщении `X` на `Y`. Вы только запутаете окружающих и помешаете в поиске ответа.

Comment: А просто просуммировать True (1) и False (0) значения возвращаемые люмбдой?
Тоесть убрать `.count(True)` и вместо `list` использовать `sum`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующий вариант решения, в котором мы проверяем принадлежность элемента к встроенному типу python, в вашем случае `str`. Атрибут `.__CLASS__` содержит ссылку на класс, к которому принадлежит объект.

```
mixture_list = [True, 1, -10, 'hello', False, 'string_1', 123, 2.5, [1, 2], 'another']

count=0
for i in mixture_list:
    if i.__class__==str:
        count+=1
print(count)
```